# Étendue d'utilisation de l'expression "interface chaise clavier"

Tags: usage, expressions

Est-ce que l'expression *interface chaise clavier* implique forcément une erreur de l'opérateur (donc serait l'équivalent de l'anglais *PEBKAC*) ou bien peut être utilisé  dans un contexte neutre pour désigner simplement l'opérateur humain sans impliquer une erreur de sa part ?

Comment: L’expression rabaisse l'humain à un accessoire sans intérêt qui n'aurait pour fonction que de faire la jonction entre la chaise et le clavier, deux objets qui eux seraient utiles et sans doute plus intelligents. Non seulement péjoratif, mais aussi vulgaire. L'utilisation de ce cliché ne grandirait pas vraiment celui qui s'en servirait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

« Interface chaise-clavier » est plutôt péjoratif, comme PEBKAC. Je n'ai pas d'étude académique à citer à ce sujet, mais la tendance est très marquée sur [les premiers résultats sur Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22interface+chaise+clavier%22), et cela correspond à mon impression personnelle.

Dans les domaines de la sécurité et de la sûreté, où l'on évalue le risque qu'un être humain nuise volontairement ou non au bon fonctionnement d'un système, on parle souvent de « composant humain » ou d'« élément humain ». L'expression « interface chaise-clavier » ne conviendrait pas dans un contexte sérieux car trop imagée, et même dans un contexte informel, elle a un côté péjoratif qui n'est pas forcément voulu (dans ces domaines, on sait que les intervenants vont faire des erreurs, et le but est d'en évaluer ou réduire les effets).

Comment: J'entends plus souvent *le facteur humain*.